# Importing jquery into module that will be included in an external resource (html)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building an ad network where a publisher will place a javascript file in their page that will be hosted on a remote cdn.

Within the javascript file I need to be able to import jquery so that I can place/write ads into the publishers site.

**Here the code that's added to the publishers site (publisher code):**

```
<script src="https://cdn.adnetwork.com/platform.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.publisher.init(123123)
</script>
```

**Here's the code that is loaded on the publisher site from my cdn (platform.js):**

```
(function (publisher) {

    publisher.init = function (id) {
        console.log('publisher id is', id)
        // make ajax get request to backend api using pub id
        // return advertiser information
        // write ads to pub site using jQuery
    }

})(window.publisher = window.publisher || {})
```

How can I accomplish this on my side so I don't have to require the publisher to include jquery with my publisher code?

I need to somehow import jquery into this self executing function so I can make ajax get requests to my local api, and once the ads are returned I need to be able to write them to the DOM on the publishers site.

I know it's possible because Google does it, I'm just not sure how they accomplish it...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had a brain freeze and just realized that I don't need jQuery to accomplish what I want. I can use XMLHttpRequest!